# Is there a way to get the release date of pip packages programatically?

Tags: python, pip

There are various tools like pip-date but I am looking for something that lists installed python packages like pip list does but with the release dates (not the install dates). It is just convenience scraping the site or the repo.

Comment: Not sure if the metadata of release dates is available through this codebase, but this might be worth exploring: https://github.com/jwodder/pypi-simple

Comment: @astrochun that looks like where it should be but they have not included it. Might try to add

Comment: There is an RSS xml https://pypi.org/rss/project/pandas/releases.xml

Comment: And there is this that apears to have some upload times https://pypi.org/pypi/pandas/json

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure how reliable it is, but you can try to call pypi.org for every installed package and extract the release date there.

Something like this:

```
import pkg_resources
import requests

for package in pkg_resources.working_set:
  (package_name, package_version) = str(package).split(' ')
  url = "https://pypi.org/project/{}/{}/".format(package_name, package_version)
  response = requests.get(url)
  
  # TODO find release date with re / beautiful soup / etree etc.
  package_date = 'TODO extract release date from response.text with re / beautifulsoup / etree etc.'
  
  print ("{} ({}): {}".format(package_name, package_version, package_date))
```

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to @DerMaddi and @astrochun have found a json api for pypi that has upload_time.

```py
In [28]: res = requests.get('https://pypi.org/pypi/pandas/json')                                                                                                                                                   

In [29]: d = res.json()                                                                                                                                                                                            

In [30]: d.keys()                                                                                                                                                                                                  
Out[30]: dict_keys(['info', 'last_serial', 'releases', 'urls'])

In [31]: d['releases']['0.7.3'][0]                                                                                                                                                                                 
Out[31]: 
{'comment_text': '',
 'digests': {'md5': 'e4876ea5882accce15f6f37750f3ffec',
  'sha256': 'b770599f37fe7ee3d30755c48c8a0916e7cc4e04fbb8d531eb2536b408b05d0d'},
 'downloads': -1,
 'filename': 'pandas-0.7.3.tar.gz',
 'has_sig': False,
 'md5_digest': 'e4876ea5882accce15f6f37750f3ffec',
 'packagetype': 'sdist',
 'python_version': 'source',
 'requires_python': None,
 'size': 1446120,
 'upload_time': '2012-04-12T19:36:20',
 'upload_time_iso_8601': '2012-04-12T19:36:20.081721Z',
 'url': 'https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e8/77/b1bd481bd6b271004ebada46baeaae0b1f892999af5290a24196604266ea/pandas-0.7.3.tar.gz',
 'yanked': False,
 'yanked_reason': None}

In [32]: d['releases']['0.7.3'][1]                                                                                                                                                                                 
Out[32]: 
{'comment_text': '',
 'digests': {'md5': 'cf566a4cc2f19e27e02360ba55f1d8d3',
  'sha256': '77c650b7d5a7e3e227c3e47dcfbebdbe76fd97562da616d0de849b75a1b5a2fc'},
 'downloads': -1,
 'filename': 'pandas-0.7.3.win32-py2.5.exe',
 'has_sig': False,
 'md5_digest': 'cf566a4cc2f19e27e02360ba55f1d8d3',
 'packagetype': 'bdist_wininst',
 'python_version': '2.5',
 'requires_python': None,
 'size': 919743,
 'upload_time': '2012-04-12T19:40:30',
 'upload_time_iso_8601': '2012-04-12T19:40:30.681458Z',
 'url': 'https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/cc/dc/a6ae8f182b2285a4528560179f99e5d90d3d68df277e39d5110c5d26d7db/pandas-0.7.3.win32-py2.5.exe',
 'yanked': False,
 'yanked_reason': None}
```

Comment: Nice so in principle you can do a `pip list` and possibly pipe it `curl` and extract that information